# How do I test this internals of this promise then in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, promise, jasmine

The following async promise lives inside the Angular target that I am testing. I am unable to see the code within the 'then' being invoked and it it this code within the 'then' that I require to test.

```
angular.module('Ls', [
])

function Locale($rootScope, $http) {

  var API = {
    getAvailables: getAvailables

  };
  API.getAvailables().then(function(data) {
        ..........do stuff
     ........it what this code is doing that I want to test!!!

      });

 function getAvailables() {
      return $http.get('/l.json').then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either stub `getAvailables` to always resolve, or you could extract the callback to a separate function and test that.

Option A

`sinon.stub(API, 'getAvailables').resolves(data);`

Option B

`API.getAvailables().then(handleResponse);`

^ Test `handleResponse` function

Comment: we don't use sinon, is there a way to force the 'then' in Jasmine?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me
$httpBackend.flush() 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#writing-unit-tests-that-use-http